# Using update method 'PUT' in $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am really quiet new to angular and  was wondering if anyone could explain how I would go about making a PUT update using angular $resource. I have managed to get it working for all 'jobs' and one 'job' but was needing some help integrating the 'update' into my example and getting my head around the syntax. Had a look at the docs for $resource but could not really understand the example.

How would I go about using:

```
{ update: {method:'PUT' } }
```

and incorporating it into my example below?:

```
.factory('myApi', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        Jobs: $resource('/api/jobs'),
        Job: $resource('/api/jobs', { id: '@ref' })           
    }
}])
```

Also thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
.factory('myApi', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {
        Jobs: $resource('/api/jobs'),
        Job: $resource('/api/jobs', { id: '@ref' },{ update: { method: 'PUT' }})           
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Also just to let you know there was a missing } at the end.

Comment: `Job: $resource('/api/jobs', { id: '@ref' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' }}),`